# Cartoon with bug-eyed alien, blond guy, black-haired girl and old scientist?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, cartoon

It's a about a bug-eyed alien crashing on Earth and becoming friends with a blond protagonist (I believe there was a joke that his hair looked like bananas), a girl with black hair (who was the love interest) and an old scientist.

I can't be sure, but I think it was a European cartoon (maybe French).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe *[Monster Buster Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Buster_Club)*?

> The show takes place in a small calm town named Single Town. Single Town is two hundred years old and was founded by a man named Addison Single (who was really an alien disguised as a human). Unbeknownst to its human inhabitants, Single Town is actually a meeting place for aliens from different parts of the galaxy.

Comment: Nope Its not CG :( I think it was made somewhere around 2000-2006

Comment: Apparently it's not the answer but this seems to match the criteria well.